# ORA-22992 / ORA-06502+ORA-06512 errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using this part of code in large one :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    P.SKU, SUBSTR(X.ATTRIBUTENAME, 14, 3) ATTRIBUTECODE, X.ATTRIBUTEVALUE
FROM 
    PRODUCT@ISPSTAG2 P,
    XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(P.ATTRIBUTES_DE_AT, '<attr name="longDescription">.*?<\/attr>'))
    COLUMNS ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@name',
            ATTRIBUTEVALUE VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '/string'
) X
WHERE X.ATTRIBUTENAME LIKE 'Z_CA%'
AND DN(DOMAINID) = 'AT'
AND SKU NOT LIKE 'OFF_%' AND SKU NOT LIKE 'PDT%'
AND ATTRIBUTES_DE_AT IS NOT NULL;
```

And it throws an `ORA-22992` error.

I've made some research and a tip can to use the dual

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.SKU, SUBSTR(X.ATTRIBUTENAME, 14, 3) ATTRIBUTECODE, X.ATTRIBUTEVALUE
FROM PRODUCT@ISPSTAG2 P,
XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(P.ATTRIBUTES_DE_AT, '<attr name="longDescription">.*?<\/attr>'))
    COLUMNS ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@name',
            ATTRIBUTEVALUE VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '/string'
) X
WHERE X.ATTRIBUTENAME LIKE 'Z_CA%'
AND DN(DOMAINID) = 'AT'
AND SKU NOT LIKE 'OFF_%' AND SKU NOT LIKE 'PDT%'
AND (SELECT ATTRIBUTES_DE_AT FROM DUAL) IS NOT NULL;
```

But now I get ORA-06502/ORA-06512 errors :

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL : erreur numérique ou erreur sur une valeur
>   ORA-06512: à "SYS.XMLTYPE", ligne 272
>   ORA-06512: à ligne 1
>   06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
>   *Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable declared NUMBER(2).
>   *Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so that values do not violate constraints.

But, I executed the first one on ISPSTAG2 and it works, but the second one on ISPSTAG2 returns me the same ORA-06502/ORA-06512 errors so the issue is with the dual subquery.

I also tried to create a view on ISPSTAG2 using DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR with 4000 characters but same error.

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: Well when I remove the DN(DOMAINID) oracle does not throw any errors: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1cbbd6e21fb237914f460af50e2d62d8 what is DN ?

Comment: DN() is just an inner join function which helps me to filter with the country.
You can replace it with :
```
AND P.DOMAINID = 'SG0K_clgVhkAAAFSNGUf5PTo'
```

I also tried to select just ATTRIBUTES_DE_AT and no error, but when I use any function like XMLISVALID, XMLTABLE, etc it returns me an error, so I guess a XML error inside the LOB, but how can I find it ? Using ROWNUM < 10 the request is good, but < 100 it returns the error

Comment: And when you remove that line of code does the second code work ?

Answer (score 0):

If forgot to use the (SELECT ATTRIBUTES_DE_AT FROM DUAL) subquery inside the XMLTYPE...

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.SKU, SUBSTR(X.ATTRIBUTENAME, 14, 3) ATTRIBUTECODE, X.ATTRIBUTEVALUE
FROM PRODUCT@ISPSTAG2 P,
XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(**(SELECT ATTRIBUTES_DE_AT FROM DUAL)**, '<attr name="longDescription">.*?<\/attr>'))
    COLUMNS ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@name',
            ATTRIBUTEVALUE VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '/string'
) X
WHERE X.ATTRIBUTENAME LIKE 'Z_CA%'
AND DN(DOMAINID) = 'AT'
AND SKU NOT LIKE 'OFF_%' AND SKU NOT LIKE 'PDT%'
AND (SELECT ATTRIBUTES_DE_AT FROM DUAL) IS NOT NULL;
```

The thing I don't understand is that when don't use the subquery in the IS NOT NULL filter I have the the ORA-22992 error (using distant LOB), so why I have a different error not using the dual subquery, which is the same distant LOB ?

Anyway for you for your time/help :)